# How to wait for multiple async http calls to return before executing a block of code

Tags: angular, typescript

Im aware of **forkJoin** but my problem is Unlike the following code

```
    getAllData() {
      let riskTable = this.getRiskTable();
      let risks = this.getAllRisks(); // should also return some observable
    
      forkJoin(riskTable, risks).subscribe(_ => {
        // all observables have been completed
      });
    }
```

Iam doing  a lot of computation inside each subscribe method and http calls are made from different methods and computations are done inside that method itself ..I cant combine all theses methods into one because that will result in duplication of code as I need to invoke these methods separately in multiple places

ex:

```
    ngOnInit(){
     this.getAllPartners()
     this.getAllUoms();
     this.getAllproductsByLocation();
     this.getAllLocations();
     this.getAllOperationTypes();

    }
    
    
      
      
getAllLocations(){
              this .queryResourceService.
              getAllLocationsForTransfersUsingGET(this.allLocParams).subscribe((data: 
               LocationDTO[]) => {
              this.locationDTOs = data;}) , 
              error=>console.log("error"),
              ()=> this.spinner.hide();
          }
getAllPartners(){
          this.spinner.show();
          this.queryResourceService.getAllPartnersUsingGET 
          (this.partnerParams).subscribe((data)={},
          error=>console.log("err"),
          ()=> this.spinner.hide())
        }
    
    
getAllproductsByLocation() {
                 this.spinner.show();
                 this.queryResourceService.
                 getAllProductsByLocationUsingGET(this.getAllProductsUsingGETParams)
                 .subscribe((data: StockDTO[]) => {
                                   this.stockDTOs = data;
                         },
                         error=>console.log("error"),
                         ()=>  this.spinner.hide())
      }
```

Now I need to execute a block of code after all these **http** calls inside the  methods return

```
 this.getAllPartners()
 this.getAllUoms();
 this.getAllproductsByLocation();
 this.getAllLocations();
 this.getAllOperationTypes();
```

i.e. after all these method calls return as well as **async** call backs inside them are completed

,How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to subscribe to each of the HTTP observables individually. You could use RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) (or [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap)), [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operators to do your computations inside each HTTP request and return the observable.

```js
import { of, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, finalize, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

getAllLocations() {
  return this.queryResourceService.getAllLocationsForTransfersUsingGET(this.allLocParams).pipe(
    map((data: LocationDTO[]) => {
      this.locationDTOs = data;
      return data;          // <-- return `data`
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.log("error");
      return of(error);     // <-- remember you must return an observable from `catchError` operator
    })
  );
}

getAllPartners() {
  return this.queryResourceService.getAllPartnersUsingGET(this.partnerParams).pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      console.log("error");
      return of(error);     // <-- remember you must return an observable from `catchError` operator
    })
  );
}


getAllproductsByLocation() {
  return this.queryResourceService.getAllProductsByLocationUsingGET(this.getAllProductsUsingGETParams).pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      console.log("error");
      return of(error)      // <-- remember you must return an observable from `catchError` operator
    })
  );
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.spinner.show();
  forkJoin(
    this.getAllPartners(),
    this.getAllUoms(),
    this.getAllproductsByLocation(),
    this.getAllLocations(),
    this.getAllOperationTypes()
  ).subscribe(
    null,
    err => { },
    () => this.spinner.hide();
  );
}
```

Now you have a single source of subscription and you can control the `spinner` flag centrally. So it doesn't switch between show and hides states when multiple requests are underway. If you wish to do something when each of the observable completes individually, then you could pipe in [`finalize`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/finalize) operator along with other operators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this line `return of(error)` causes `expression expected` error

Comment: @Arjun: Please replace all `console.log("error"),` with `console.log("error");`. Notice the change in comma to semi-colon. I accidentally included commas at the end of statements instead of semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

ForkJoin can be used here. Instead of subscribing in each get function, you can return the observable and use forkJoin.

```
getAllLocations(){
    return this .queryResourceService.
        getAllLocationsForTransfersUsingGET(this.allLocParams);
}
getAllPartners(){
    this.spinner.show();
         this.queryResourceService.getAllPartnersUsingGET(this.partnerParams);
}
...
```

Then in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
    forkJoin(
        this.getAllLocations()
        this.getAllPartners();
        ...
    )
    .subscribe(([locations, partners, ...]) => {
        this.handleLocationSubscription(locations);
        this.handlePartnerSubscription(locations);
        ...
        // Perform task after all async operatiojns resolved
    });
 
}

handleLocationSubscription(data: LocationDTO[]) {
    this.locationDTOs = data;
    ...
}
```